# How do I track Firebase Analytics installs with Tag Manager

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

We are using Firebase Analytics(FA)-> Tag Manager(GTM)-> Google Analytics(GA), this works for conventional events as well as *session_start* and screen views.

How do I track Firebase Automatic events such as Install(*first_open*) / Uninstall / Crash? Such events are not being logged in GA, below is how it is being setup.

[image: event name as first_open]